# TypeScript casting arrays

Tags: casting, typescript

I'm trying to use a wrapper for a library that wants an Array as an input parameter.

I tried casting the Array, but I get an error: Cannot convert 'any[]' to 'Array'

Is there a way to make this work?

```
var rows = new Array(10);
var rows2 = <Array>rows; //<--- Cannot convert 'any[]' to 'Array'
```

Comment: I can convert the wrapper to any[], but I'd like to know why I can't cast to an Array.

Answer (score 144):

There are 4 possible conversion methods in TypeScript for arrays:

```
let x = []; //any[]

let y1 = x as number[];
let z1 = x as Array<number>;
let y2 = <number[]>x;
let z2 = <Array<number>>x;
```

The `as` operator's mostly designed for `*.tsx` files to avoid the syntax ambiguity.

Answer (score 17):

I think the right syntax is:

```
var rows2 = <Array<any>>rows;
```

That's how you cast to `interface Array<T>`

Answer (score 5):

I think this is just a bug - can you log an issue on the CodePlex site?

As a workaround, you can write `<Array><any>rows`;

Comment: Presumably the issue has been fixed. And I think you all are using GitHub now? ;)

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution for all types

```
const myArray = <MyType[]>value;
```

Comment: this do not work, if you console log the result , myArray is not a array of MyType elements