# Cast declaration variable inside for of loop

Tags: typescript, casting, typescript-typings

Is there a shorter and simplified version of casting a declaration variable inside of "for of" loop.

```
let array1: Array<String | Number>;
for (let a of array1) {
    let ab: String = <String>a;
}
```

I am aware casting the whole array would work, but tbh i would feel much more happy if i could either cast or set the datatype of declaration variable "a" instead of casting the whole array, Is something like that possible?
if i type 
`let <String>a` or `let a:String` it doesn't work.

Comment: ref  [TypeScript casting arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792695/typescript-casting-arrays)
`for (let a of  array1 as Array<string> ) `

Answer (score 26, accepted):

ref [TypeScript casting arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792695/typescript-casting-arrays)

```
let array1 : Array<string | number> = [];
array1.push('abc', 9, 'def', 10);
for (let a of  array1 as Array<string> ){
  console.log(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, `forEach` iterations on DOM NodeList would be cast like:

```
const links: NodeListOf<HTMLElement> = document.querySelectorAll('a')
links.forEach(a => a.setAttribute('target', '_blank'))
```