# Typescript and React setting initial state with empty typed array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Say I have the following snippet:

```
interface State {
  alarms: Alarm[];
}
export default class Alarms extends React.Component<{}, State> {
  state = {
    alarms: []
  };
```

Since I am trying to set `alarms: []` Typescript doesn't like it, as `[] != Alarm[]`. I found that I can use `alarms: new Array<Alarm>()` which initializes an empty typed array, however I don't really like this syntax - is there an easier/better approach?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The problem is that when you create a field in a class the compiler will type that field accordingly (either using the explicit type or an inferred type from the initialization expression such as in your case).

If you want to redeclare the field, you should specify the type explicitly :

```
export default class Alarms extends React.Component<{}, State> {
    state: Readonly<State> = {
        alarms: []
    };
}
```

Or set the state in the constructor:

```
export default class Alarms extends React.Component<{}, State> {
    constructor(p: {}) {
        super(p);
        this.state = {
            alarms: []
        };
    }
}
```

You could also cast the array to the expected type, but if there are a lot of fields it would be better to let the compiler check the object literal for you.

Comment: Do we need to use `setState()` in constructor? It seems to be possible to just use `this.state = {...}` here.

Comment: @Cerberus you don't need to .. but you can and it doesn't duplicate the type of the state in the `extends` clause and on the `state` (as `Readonly<State>`) but either solution should work :)

Comment: To quote the docs: "You **should not call setState()** in the `constructor()`." https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Answer (score 26):

Would

`alarms: [] as Alarm[]`

work for Typescript and for you ?

See this question on how you can cast arrays in Typescript : [TypeScript casting arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792695/typescript-casting-arrays)

Answer (score -1):

Declaration:

`alarms: Array<Alarm>`

Initialization in state :

```
this.setState({
var1:'',
var2:''
});
```

I prefer the above declaration