# How to set initial React state in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state

What is the proper way to initialize state when using typescript and react.  The following throws an error because obviously currentVehicle isn't allowed to be an empty object.  What should the initial state be?  What are best practicies?

```
 interface State{
    currentVehicle:Vehicle
}

export default class extends Component<Props, State> {
   state:State={
       currentVehicle:{}
     }
  }
```

Comment: Since you have passed a `State` interface to the React.Component you should just initialize it like `state = { currentVehicle: {} }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript and React setting initial state with empty typed array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51305171/typescript-and-react-setting-initial-state-with-empty-typed-array)

Answer (score 5):

You can cast it:

```
state:State = {
    currentVehicle:{} as Vehicle
}
```

Comment: The underlying value will still be an empty object which can cause errors during compile time if you try to access a prop in the empty object.

Comment: You'll only get a RefError if you try to access nested props, but top level props will just return undefined. Regardless though you should probably be null checking or at least initiating a state with all required values.

Answer (score 3):

In this case i would define the type of currentVehicle as **Vehicle** or **null** and assign to it a null value on the initial state

```
interface State {
   currentVehicle: Vehicle | null
}

export default class extends Component<Props, State> {
  state: State = {
     currentVehicle: null
  }
}
```

A second option would be to define **currentVehicle** as an optional parameter. That way you don't have to initialise it.

```
interface State {
   currentVehicle?: Vehicle // optional
}

export default class extends Component<Props, State> {

  /** you only define your state without defining state.currentVehicle */
  state: State = {}
}
```