# Cast array with filter method

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have to cast this:

```
let selections = list.filter(obj => obj.type === "myType");
```

I get an error with a filter which says

> filter does not exist on type 'NodeType'

I tried to follow these suggestions
[TypeScript casting arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792695/typescript-casting-arrays)

```
let selections = <NodeType[]>list.filter(obj => obj.type === "myType");
```

but I still get the same error, I can't see how to fix this. 
In pure javascript, it works.

Update: thanks to answers below which makes me realize I call the right method when I tested in console and a wrong one in my code editor.

Comment: `filter does not exist on type 'NodeType'` that makes it sound like `list` is a `NodeType`, not an array. How was `list` created?

Comment: yes list is of NodeType returned by some API and I want to cast it into an array only for applying filter. In pure javascript I don't need to, it works in chrome console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this *exact same thing* works in pure JavaScript, not just something sort of like it? If `list` is an array which comes from the browser DOM, it's likely that really, truly it doesn't have a `filter` method. Those DOM arrays are only "`ArrayLike`", not true JavaScript arrays.

Try `Array.from(list)` or `Array.from(list as NodeType[])` and see if that helps.

Comment: of course it works in pure javascript: it's just an array of objects.

Comment: @user310291, my point is that "just an array" isn't always what it seems. The DOM contains arrays that aren't true JavaScript arrays. These arrays do have a `length` property, and they can be accessed by numeric indices, but they *don't* have methods like `filter`, `map`, `forEach`, etc. Casting doesn't, and can't, add methods that aren't there in the first place.

Comment: ok thanks, I realized I call the right method when I tested in console and a wrong one in my code editor.

Answer (score -1):

Your error message complains about the `filter` method not being available on a `NodeType`
In your example you specified a `NodeType` **Array**.

Try this:

```
<NodeType>list
```

It's still not an array though.

Comment: list must be an array for filter method.

Comment: but thanks, It makes me realize I call the right method when I tested in console and a wrong one in my code editor.