# Parsing error: Identifier expected - With angle brackets casting

Tags: typescript

I have this in a Vue component:

```
  data: () => ({
    articles: [] as MyModel[],
  }),
```

..which works fine. But when I turn it to this style of [casting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35181988/413785):

```
  data: () => ({
    articles: <GetLatestNewsArticlesModel[]>[],
  }),
```

..it gives me `Parsing error: Identifier expected` error.

Why? And is there anything I could do for it to allow me to use the second style?

Thanks.

Comment: The first style is there to avoid ambiguity where angle brackets have other uses, like in TSX or Vue SFCs - why don't you want to use it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - No technical reason really. I just subjectively like the second approach better, and am curious on why it's not working atm. If I have to stick with the `as` syntax, it's not a big deal.

Comment: ["...it is now recommended that you just use `as foo` for consistency"](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion#as-foo-vs-less-than-foo-greater-than)

Comment: Fair enough. I'll keep using the `as` syntax then. Thanks.